# How to merge tuples from macros in DBT

Tags: sql, jinja2, dbt

Looking to merge tuples from different macros into one. As in the following code, the intention is to merge the output of

```
{% macro days15() %}
    (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)                                                                                                                           
{% endmacro %}

{% macro days69() %}
    (6,7,8,9)
{% endmacro %}

{% macro days19() %}
    {{ days15() }} UNION ALL {{ days69() }}
{% endmacro %}
```

With the expectations that `days19` returns a tuple with values union of `days15` and `days69`.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am not answering your question directly, but a better and more DRY approach for your "use case" is to create 1 macro with 2 parameters, like this:

```
{% macro days(from, to) %}
    (
        {%- for i in range(from, to + 1) -%}
        {{ i }}{{ ',' if not loop.last }}
        {%- endfor -%}
    )
{% endmacro %}
```

you can then call the macro with `days(1, 5)`, `days(6, 9)` and `days(1, 9)`